# TMap's opinion on double programming

Tags: tmap

At my organization all our extensive calculations and business logic, of which we have a lot, are programmed in a C-like language. One way of testing them is to re-program them (based on specifications and human domain knowledge) in VBA + Excel and compare input / output. So we are basically programming our calculations twice. What does TMap says about this method of software testing?

While I am at I would like to know what academia thinks about this.